# Windows 7: restore from ISO

Tags: windows-7, imaging

I made an image of my boot SSD using Linux directly to an ISO for safe keeping on another hard drive. Now that installation is messed up somehow I want to restore from the ISO. I know Windows 7 recovery disk has that cool "Restore from system image", but from what I have read, that only works with .vhd's, not .iso's.

Is there a way to restore from an ISO?

Comment: what tool did you use? DD? partimage?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the same method that allowed you to take this image, but do it in reverse. The exact method would depend on how you made the image.

Out of curiosity, did you use 'dd' to make the image, or did you just recursively copy the files, because if it's the latter, you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If that ISO is bootable, you may try to boot off it (grub can boot off .iso files) and see if it offers a restoration prompt.

If it is not bootable, then you should mount the .iso file and check what files are there. Given the files, we can try to figure out what method you used to backup and how to restore.